# yii2 как узнать изменился ли конкретное поле

Tags: php, yii2

подскажите по yii2
как узнать изменился ли конкретное поле
например есть 4 поля pole1, pole2, pole3, pole4 и другие 4 поля pole1_date, pole2_date, pole3_date, pole4_date которым попадает даты при изменениях.

При Update если в поле pole1 попадает значение или изменяется, должен попадать текущая дата в pole1_date при сохранении,
точно также при изменение или попадание значения в поле pole2, сохраняется дата в поле pole2_date и так далее. 
Так при каждом изменении полей (pole1, pole2, pole3, pole4) сохраняется новая дата их соответствующих полей (pole1_date, pole2_date, pole3_date, pole4_date)
Как это можно осуществить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `getDirtyAttribute()` класса `yii\db\ActiveRecord`

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#getDirtyAttributes()-detail

Answer (score 1):

Если используется ActiveRecord, то также можно использовать метод isAttributeChanged():

```
$pole1IsChanged = $myModel->isAttributeChanged('pale_1');
```